# Android layout manager for equal sized grid

Tags: android, android-layout

For learning Android I'd like to write a tiny calculator application. At the bottom (of a vertical screen) I want to show a grid of buttons, at least 4 equal-wide rows and 5 equal-high columns. The application should run on Android 2.3 ("Gingerbread") or later. Is there a layout manager that could be used for that, especially down to 2.3 - or should I write my own one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android.widget.GridView` which was added in **Added in API level 1** and will meet your expectations. Just FYI https://www.raywenderlich.com/127544/android-gridview-getting-started

Comment: Is there a way to make a control spread over multiple cells horizontally/vertically, e.g. for a double-size Enter button?

Comment: You can merge cells horizontall/vertically but in that case you need to use Gridlayout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the `GridLayout` only is available from API 14 (Android 4.0), so I can't use it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the API level on which you are working upon. You can use android.support.v7.gridlayout
 for backwards compatibility